# What is being said in this short audio clip? (10 seconds)

Tags: translation

[Here](https://instaud.io/3ghi) is the audio clip. Thanks for your help, I apreciate that.

The translation I currently have is "Think of it as a holiday and
mess with the auditors".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 형식적인 거니까 휴가라고 생각하고 감사과 애들이랑 놀다 와

"It's just perfunctory. So think of it as a holiday and mess with the auditors." (that's what it literally means besides a little sense of humor put in there)

---

- "감사과 애들"

  "감사과 애들" (the auditors; comptrollers) here is a dishonorable speaking of "감사관"/"감사과의 직원 분".

  What auditors would do: [관세청 감사관](https://www.customs.go.kr/kcshome/cop/smt/djm/selectDeptDetail.do?deptJobId=DEPT_JOB_00000000004&hdeptCode=000000217&layoutMenuNo=244)

---

- "애들이랑 놀다 와"

  "애들이랑 놀다 와" literally "Go play with those kids" is a common phrase in movies.
  It is said when someone has to go through a tough event (like a business meeting with the auditors) and you tell that person to do so, in a sense comforting that person, kinda like "take it easy". What it means is more closer to "just have fun with them" rather than 'to treat someone bad or in a rude way'. When this is said the two in the conversation must be very close/friendly to each other.

---

Comment: What do you meanhere with "auditor"? That's my biggest doubt! And about "mess with" you mean to make them piss off?

Comment: @Bafforasta The more direct translation for the “mess with” part (“`-이랑 놀다(가)`”) would be “have fun with,” which, depending on the context, might be a playful way of saying “to piss someone off.”

Comment: Okay so I edited my post a bit. I hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

형식적인 거니까 휴가라고 생각하고 감사과 애들이랑 놀다 와

This may be a dialogue in some movie. Through this sentence, we can
not understand whole situation. But typical example is as follows :

In my thought, it seems to be a *periodic* or *ritual* monitoring so
that you would visit to the inspection department with a light
heart.